# Spotfire Custom Formating and Custom expression

Tags: spotfire

I have a column in my data table which reflects request Date and Time in the following format: `3/4/2020 13:00:00 PM`, `3/5/2020 15:00:00 PM`. I am trying to use a custom formatting option to insert a computed column which reflects the codes that I am planning to use.
**e.g**: any request which falls between `08:00:00` to `16:30:00` will be in Time Zone "A" while anything between `16:30:00` to `02:00:00` will be in Time Zone  "B".

Can you please help what is the formula that I can use to get this result? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the Time() function to extract the time from you datetime column :

```
Case when Time([DateTimeColumn]) >= Time(8,0,0,0) and Time([DateTimeColumn]) <= Time(16,30,0,0)  then 'TimeZone A' 
    else 'Time Zone B' 
    end
```